# Insert lines at the end of text file if not exist using DOS

Tags: batch-file, insert, dos, lines

I need batch file.bat to do

I have filename.txt with content:

```
blah blah
....
Miss Phuong
I love you all. Miss Phuong
End of file
```

I want to insert following lines at the end if the line is not exist:

```
I love you all
Miss Phuong
```

After run it is:

```
blah blah
....
Miss Phuong
I love you all. Miss Phuong
End of file
I love you all
```

"Miss Phuong" will be not added because line exist.
"I love you all" will be added because string "I love you all" exist but that line is "I love you all. Miss Phuong"

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
@echo off

findstr /x /c:"I love you all" text.txt >nul || echo I love you all>> text.txt
findstr /x /c:"Miss Phuong" text.txt >nul || echo Miss Phuong>> text.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `FOR /F` to traverse through the lines of the file. If the value is not amongst each line you find, you can add it using `echo Miss Phuong >> YourTextFile.txt